# How to find all volumes that btrfs df prints out?

Tags: filesystem, btrfs

i don't understand where the second data "container" comes from:

```
ocean@nas:/mnt$ sudo btrfs filesystem df /
Data, RAID1: total=3.00GiB, used=1.70GiB
Data, single: total=1.00GiB, used=0.00B  <-- this one
System, RAID1: total=32.00MiB, used=16.00KiB
Metadata, RAID1: total=1.00GiB, used=73.86MiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=32.00MiB, used=0.00B
```

how can i find out where this comes from?

It suddenly appeared after balancing my drives:

- new linux on btrfs filesystem, with two unbalanced hdds:

  ```
  ocean@nas:/mnt$ sudo btrfs filesystem df /
  Data, single: total=2.01GiB, used=1.70GiB
  System, DUP: total=8.00MiB, used=16.00KiB
  Metadata, DUP: total=1.00GiB, used=72.38MiB
  GlobalReserve, single: total=32.00MiB, used=0.00B
  ```
- then i balanced the btrfs:

  ```
  ocean@nas:/mnt$ sudo btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /
  Done, had to relocate 5 out of 5 chunks
  ```
- output after balacing:

  ```
     ocean@nas:/mnt$ sudo btrfs filesystem show
     Label: 'hddArray1'  uuid: 925b7c82-f7da-4eda-89ce-990cc63f53ad
     Total devices 2 FS bytes used 1.77GiB
     devid    1 size 3.63TiB used 4.03GiB path /dev/sda3
     devid    2 size 3.64TiB used 5.03GiB path /dev/sdb
  ```
- and (as above):

  ```
    ocean@nas:/mnt$ sudo btrfs filesystem df /
    Data, RAID1: total=3.00GiB, used=1.70GiB
    Data, single: total=1.00GiB, used=0.00B  <-- this one
    System, RAID1: total=32.00MiB, used=16.00KiB
    Metadata, RAID1: total=1.00GiB, used=73.86MiB
    GlobalReserve, single: total=32.00MiB, used=0.00B
  ```
- and:

  ```
   ocean@nas:/mnt$ sudo btrfs device usage -g /
   /dev/sda3, ID: 1
     Device size:          3717.55GiB
     Data,RAID1:              3.00GiB
     Metadata,RAID1:          1.00GiB
     System,RAID1:            0.03GiB
     Unallocated:          3713.52GiB

   /dev/sdb, ID: 2
      Device size:          3726.02GiB
      Data,single:             1.00GiB
      Data,RAID1:              3.00GiB
      Metadata,RAID1:          1.00GiB
      System,RAID1:            0.03GiB
      Unallocated:          3720.99GiB
  ```

Thanks!

Comment: So, you see where is the 1GB?

Comment: yes, now  i get it: usage of disk != size of disk. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different disk sizes. The difference is 1 GB.

That is why there is 1GB "single" entry.

The effect of this IMO will be that when the RAID is full, some data may be stored as "single".

If you want to avoid this you can create a partition table on `/dev/sdb` and create there a partition exactly same size as `/dev/sda3`.

Comment: is there an easy way, how i can create a partition table on /dev/sdb at this point?

Comment: An easy way is to remove `sdb` from the filesystem, then create a partition table there, then add again as a partition, then balance. It will take some time to balance though.

Comment: I created a partition on sdb with the **exact** same size of sda3, then i added this partition and balanced btrfs  again. But there was still a data block, as i described in my question. Now i found the solution: `btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 -sconvert=raid1 -f /` (i think the force flag do the magic)

Comment: You can write your own answer to your question. It will be helpful for others.

Comment: But that is a bit weird. `-f` does a different thing.